# Magento 2 get the latest wishlist collection

Tags: magento2, wishlist, customer-login

How we can get the latest wishlist collection for a particular login customer without cache clean in Magento2?

Comment: use cachable="false" in layout file

Comment: Do not use cachable="false" that stops the cache working for any effected page. Where are you trying to get the information and how are you trying to get it? (Pages types, phtml file, ajax request etc.)

Answer (score 1):

> **Try this**

```
protected $itemsCollection;

public function __construct(
    ............................................................
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory $itemsCollection,
    ............................................................
) {
    $this->itemsCollection = $itemsCollection;
}

public function getAllWishlistItems()
{
    return $this->itemsCollection->create();
}
```